# CakePHP check if user is logged in inside a view

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code:

```
    <?php

    if (!$this->Auth->user())
    {
        echo $this->element('header');
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->element('header-bar');
    }

    ?>
```

inside my view which should show a different header for logged in users but throws the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Auth [APP/views/layouts/page.ctp, line 17]
Fatal error: Call to a member function user() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/thehive/app/views/layouts/page.ctp on line 17
```

How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you serve a different view for a different user action (i.e. unauthenticated access), shouldn't you just serve a different view?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Note:** Also check out meotimdihia's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901685/cakephp-check-if-user-is-logged-in-inside-a-view/#6497338). It's got a **lot** of upvotes.

---

The Auth component is for use in the Controller. You'll want to check for authorization in the controller, then set a variable for the view, e.g., `$this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());`. Then in your view you can do:

```
if (!$authUser)
{
    echo $this->element('header');
}
```

If you want this to be done automatically for all controller methods, you can look into modifying `cake/libs/controller/app_controller.php` so that it includes the Auth component.

Comment: This is OUTDATED as of CakePHP 2.x!! Use jesal's answer!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/18198982/1294758

Answer (score 90):

You don't need to do `$this->set(compact('authUser'));`
only use this in View:

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')){
// do something 
}
```

Comment: This is OUTDATED as of CakePHP 2.x!! Use jesal's answer!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/18198982/1294758

Answer (score 50):

As of CakePHP 2.x:

```
<?php if (AuthComponent::user('id')): ?>
   Logged in as <?= AuthComponent::user('name') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: For CakePHP 3 this causes a fatal error, but `$this->Session->read` gives a deprecated warning with the actual code you should use, as in @LeeNelson's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29759420/327074)

Answer (score 24):

To summarize the answers on this page, evaluate one of the following based on which version of CakePHP you are using:

For version 1.x

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User')
```

For version 2.x

```
AuthComponent::user('id')
```

For version 3.x

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id')
```

For version 4.x, using the [Authentication component](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html)

```
$this->loadHelper('Authentication.Identity');
...
$this->Identity->isLoggedIn()
```

Comment: how about cakephp4?

Answer (score 11):

This works in Cakephp 3+ (juts modify: "Auth.User.username" to suit your session data)

```
<?php

if (is_null($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username'))) {

    echo "....logged out";

} else {

    echo "You are Logged in As " . $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username'); 

}

?>
```

Comment: I just can't understand why all functions and ways are changing so frequently in cakephp. You learn cake 2.4 then 3.0 comes with all new syntax. Very annoying.

Comment: Hey RN Kushwaha, CakePHP follow PHP, there is a PHP 7, did you use all new things in that version? CakePHP 1.x to 2.x make things better only, CakePHP 3 is all new framework made from zero to acomplish to namespaces and all new features in the language.

Comment: @RNKushwaha the same thing happened to code igniter, laravel and yii.. we have to frequently follow latest technology

Comment: @aswzen I understand that but my point is that there must be some wrapper functions that need to be updated. So whenever a change occurs we need to update only that wrapper function.

Comment: **Attention**, you may have to be using `getRequest()` and `getSession()` as of CakePHP 4+. Either way, gets me *Error: Call to undefined method App\View\AppView::getRequest()* when used from within a layout

Answer (score 5):

its been a while that I have used CakePHP but as far as I can remember CakePHP
doesn't support Auth in View. What you can do of course is set a variable in the
controller to use it in the view

```
<?
   class AppController {
     ....
     function beforeFilter(){
       ....
       $this->set('auth',$this->Auth);
     }
     ....
   }
?>
```

and then use it in the view like this

```
$auth->....
```

or you can use the AuthHelper written by Ritesh Agrawal

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ragrawal/2008/07/29/authhelper

**BTW**

I think if it comes to only test if somebody is logged in @webbiedave's answer
is better MVC style wise.

Nevertheless if you have to access userdata in view the just extract the userinfo
from Auth component and set it in the controller as I showed you and use it in the view

Regards

Comment: beforeFile should be beforeFilter

Comment: This is OUTDATED as of CakePHP 2.x!! Use jesal's answer!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/18198982/1294758

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class AppController extends Controller{
    $this->user = false;

   public function beforeFilter(){
     $this->user = $this->Auth->user();
   }

   public function beforeRender(){
      $this->set('logged_user',$this->user);
   }
}
```

Now You can check $logged_user in the view as

```
if($logged_user){
  // users logged in $logged_user have all the details
}else{
  // not logged in
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in cakephp 3 you can check authentication session in the view like this

```
if($this->request->Session()->read('Auth.User')){
//do when login
}
else{
 //do not login
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone out in cakephp version 3.7.8 session has been depriciated to getSession so to update Lee Nielsen's comment

```
if (is_null($this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User.username'))) {

echo "....logged out";

} else {

echo "You are Logged in As " . $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User.username'); 

}
```

Comment: Same may happen to `request` → `getRequest()`

Answer (score 2):

For cakephp 4.2.6 Strawberry with Auth Component

```
        <?php 
        // Note: Change email param to yours
        if (is_null($this->request->getSession()->read('Auth')->email)) {
        ?>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Login'), [ 'action' => 'login','controller' => 'Users']) ?>
            

        <?php 
        } else { ?>
            <?= $this->Html->link(__('Logout'), [ 'action' => 'logout','controller' => 'Users']) ?>
            
        <?php }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the user details from a controller, preferably the AppController which is inherited by all controllers across your site. Create/amend your app_controller.php to contain this `beforeFilter();` method.

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

function beforeFilter() {
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

This will set a var called `$user` to the views which will be empty if the user is not logged in, or contain their data if they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In the views (or layout)
$session->check('Auth.User.id');

//In controller
$this->Auth->User('id');
```

Comment: `$this->Session`- but other than that I would go for this approach!

Answer (score 0):

I found something worth mentioning, In CakePHP 3.x session handler is deprecated,

if we want to access session in view, we can do it via request handler. we have to use

```
<?php
   // For CakePHP 3.x to access all user information
   $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');

  // For CakePHP 3.x to check session
  if($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id')) {

  }
?>
```