# Checking user auth in controllers with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on the blog/user auth tutorial for cakephp and trying to add a couple features to get the hang of things.I'm on this page of the auth right now
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I'm trying to display a link to logout only if the user is logged in, and a login link only if the user is logged out. I'm trying to follow the advice from this post [CakePHP check if user is logged in inside a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901685/cakephp-check-if-user-is-logged-in-inside-a-view) but I'm a bit confused.

**edit- To make sure my authuser was being found correctly I simply put an echo "test" statement in there. The links were working fine, however, when I removed the echo statement the link will only display login, even when I am logged in. I can't figure out why the links are only working properly when I echo something in my element.**

So, on my posts/index page I have the following

```
<?php
if($this->element('authuser') == TRUE){   
?>
    <p><?php echo $this->Html->link('Log In', array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login')); ?></p>
<?
}
   else{ 
?>
    <p><?php echo $this->Html->link('Log Out', array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'logout')); ?></p>
<?
}
?>
```

My element authuser.ctp contains

```
<?
 $authuser = AuthComponent::user();

if($authuser){
  RETURN TRUE;
}
 echo "test"; //when this is commented out the link on posts/index only displays login
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get current loged in user in view by calling static method

```
$authUser = AuthComponent::user();
```

Instead of passing it from action, in this way you can get currenly loged user anywhere.

Anyway i recommend you add this logic into [element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html) and reuse it.

Comment: Thanks, that was surprisingly simple!

Comment: I can't seem to get the element working 100%. I'm slightly confused on  something, I updated my code above.

Comment: You are using it wrong. Element returns rendered html/string, so what element() is returning there is "test"

Comment: I got it to work, not sure if I'm using it properly though. I echo $authUser = AuthComponent::user(); and then call that element in an if statement.